# How to implement clock divider to universal shift register

Tags: vhdl, counter, clock, fpga, shift-register

I'm trying to make a VHDL code for 4-bit universal shift register, where I want to load 4 bits and choose the shift-operation from the ctrl. I don't know how to implement a clock divider to run the outputs on a FPGA.

Here is my code so far:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity shift_register is
  generic(N : integer := 4);
  port(
    clk, reset : in  std_logic;
    ctrl       : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    d          : in  std_logic_vector((N-1) downto 0);
    q          : out std_logic_vector((N-1) downto 0)
    );
end shift_register;

architecture Behavioral of shift_register is

  signal r_reg  : std_logic_vector((N-1) downto 0);
  signal r_next : std_logic_vector((N-1) downto 0);
begin
  process(clk, reset)
  begin
    if(reset = '1') then
      r_reg <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then
      r_reg <= r_next;
    end if;
  end process;

  with ctrl select
    r_next <=
    r_reg                      when "00",   --do nothing
    r_reg(N-2 downto 0) & d(0) when "01",   --shift left
    d(N-1) & r_reg(N-1 downto 1)when "10",  --shift right
                     d when others;         --load

  q <= r_reg;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: How is the clock divider question related to the shown shift register?  Can you describe in more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: No sign of a clock divider, no indication of original clock rate nor target clock rate, ratio, target device/vendor, ...

Comment: @MortenZilmer I want to load some input bits by using switches on fpga. The ctrl will choose which way the bits will go. And the result will be shown on LED's on the fpga. So I just want to implement a clock that will shift every second.

Comment: @user2466860: Is there a `clk` input on the FPGA already.  I assume so, since the `ctrl` and `d` must be synchronous to this `clk`.  Then this `clk` can be used to derive an enable signal that is asserted a single cycle every second, and this enable can then be used to make the desired update.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Thanks. How should I modify the code now? I'm quite new to VHDL programming and I'm very bad with clocks.

Comment: @user2466860: Some example code for clock divider in answer below.  Not that you must then apply the `enable` where it is to control the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divider code template with `enable` asserted a single cycle every `RATIO` clock cycles:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture syn of mdl is
  constant RATIO  : natural := 10;
  signal prescale : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);  -- Scale to fit RATIO - 1
  signal enable   : std_logic;
begin

  process (clk, reset) is
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      enable   <= '0';
      prescale <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(RATIO - 1, prescale'length));
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if unsigned(prescale) = 0 then
        enable   <= '1';
        prescale <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(RATIO - 1, prescale'length));
      else
        enable   <= '0';
        prescale <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(prescale) - 1);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture;
```